# How do I use "Not Equal to" in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

How do I show a message if none of the rows returned have a specific value?

If all of the results in a report have a status of "OK", I want to return a message indicating that there were no warnings.

How can I do that?
Steve

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the first line. The second line is correct. If ALL of the rows have a status of "OK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was simple, I was using "!=", I needed to use "<>".

Problem solved.
Sc